# Как узнать координаты всех отображенных placemarks в поле зрения mapView?

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Я добавил на карту mapObjects с помощью
 `let mapObj = collection.addPlacemark(with: YMKPoint(latitude: MapObjDict["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: MapObjDict["longitude"] as! Double), image: self.ObjectMark)`

Как можно по нажатию специальной кнопки узнать, какие placemarks из всех объектов находятся в поле зрения mapView?

Comment: В Placemark есть параметр options.visible, попробуй пройтись по всем меткам в возьми только те которые options.visible == true и получи их координаты

Comment: @DmitriyLeaf Спасибо большое!

Comment: Все получилось? :)

Comment: Да, в цикле прошел по всем меткам, но visible как я понял - это свойство объекта, которое описывает, будет ли объект в принципе виден на карте или скрыт. Поэтому я задал условия вхождения объекта в квадрат экрана